# Реализация прикрепления меню или блока навигации при скролинге

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

Есть `header`, который расположен выше меню навигации. Нужно сделать так чтобы, навигация при скролинге и при прохождении через header прикрепляла блока навигации, который естественно находится ниже header. Код вроде есть под эту реализации. Вариантов его реализации много с другими плагинами и просто с помощью js и css. В данном случае мне его просто нужно прикрепить. 
Код следующий:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
    $(document).scroll (function() {
        if ($(document).scrollTop() > $('header').height () + 10) 
       $('nav').addClass ('fixed');

        else 
            $('nav').removeClass ('fixed');
    )};

</script>
```

Возможно скрипт нужно вставлять рядом с тегом `<meta>`, но не думаю, что в этом проблема. Также могу ещё разметку привести, но не думаю, что в этом проблема. Если появиться такой вопрос, в комментариях могу привести. И также класс добавляется такой, но это тоже не так важно главное чтобы, скрипт работал:

```
.fixed{
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    opacity: 0.97;
}
```

Comment: Сколько вожусь с этим вопросом до сих по не могу понять, почему class не добавляется. Пробовал по совету версию jquery  поменять, но всё без толку. Скрипт как не работал, так и не работает.

Comment: Ибо у Вас тут ошибка: `...ss ('fixed') )};`. Надо `});`, а не `)};`. А так, то Ваш пример рабочий вполне.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Скролл не в документе (`document`) происходит, а окне (`window`).
Вот рабочий вариант)

```js
$(window).bind('scroll',function(){// Используем обработчик по скроллу
  var ScrollPos = $(this).scrollTop(), // Определяем позицию скролла
      HeaderHeight = $('.header').height(); // Определяем высоту шапки
      
  if(ScrollPos>HeaderHeight) { // Если позиция скролла больше высоты шапки, т.е. ниже шапки, то..
    $('.menu').addClass('fixed'); // Добавляем класс для меню
    // Фикс, т.к. контент уходит выше, ибо менюшка "ушла"
    $('.content').css('margin-top','50px'); //Высота меню
  } else { // Если меньше, то
    $('.menu').removeClass('fixed'); // Удаляем класс у меню
    $('.content').css('margin-top','0'); // удаляем фикс
  }
});
```

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
}
.header {
  height: 100px;
  background: #666;
}
.menu {
  height: 50px;
  background: #333;
  color: #fff;
}
.menu.fixed {
  position: fixed;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
}
.content {
  height: 1000px;
  background: #999;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="header">Хеадер</div>
<div class="menu">Меню</div>
<div class="content">Контент</div>
```

Comment: Спасибо, сейчас попробую у себя реализовать. Возился уже дня два и думал, что таких скриптов еще нужно будет, сделать несколько для полноценного рабочего, красивого варианта, нужно еще уменьшение текста сделать в блоке div и наверно еще уменьшение блока при скроллинге, прямо как на сайте transparency.org к примеру. Но это я уже будут возиться дальше, в общем спасибо.

Comment: Интересно принципиально, ли использование блока div  в виде контейнера, потому что куда не загляну, реализую с помощью блоков header и nav

Comment: @АлександрАлександ, `<nav></nav>` вроде помогает поисковикам, но это не точно. Везде меню по разному реализовывается, где-то по старинке `<li></li>`.

Comment: Возможно с сервером ещё не разобрался, да вроде люди пишут что он и не нужен, при разработке я имею ввиду. Я всегда проверял работу javascript только на сервере, придётся наверно его подключить и сайт связать, заодно и с базой. Я просто соединил html и css. Вроде все работает и в выполнении работает, просто у меня верстка более сложная, я наверно намудрил. Что-то не сходиться опять... Разберёмся в общем, вопрос в любом случае исчерпан, спасибо...